# Can you copy out a VM's vhdx with vTPM enabled on Hyper-V to another machine?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

I have enabled vTPM on a virtual machine in Hyper-V with bitlocker configured on my desktop (desktop A).

Followed the links below:

https://askme4tech.com/how-enable-vtpm-windows-server-2016-hyper-v

https://pureinfotech.com/enable-tpm-secure-boot-hyperv-install-windows-11/

However, I am able to copy out the VM's vhdx from desktop A and created a new VM on another desktop (desktop B) using the same vhdx. I can boot into the VM and login to the VM on desktop B.

Not sure if this vTPM is working as intended? Or is it suppose to prevent booting into the VM when the entire physical hard disk of desktop A gets extracted and mounted as an external disk on desktop B?

Comment: Have you used bitlocker inside VM? vTPM just adds key storage for bitlocker, but doesn't encrypt VM

Comment: I am confused is BitLocker enabled on the guest oS or the host OS? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the comments.

I re-attempted the scenario with enabled BitLocker enabled in the VM and vTPM enabled in Hyper-V on desktop A. When the VM's vhdx from desktop A is copied out and booted in desktop B, it now prompts for a recovery key.